# R Stat Stargazer - How to drop percentiles in summary table?

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I am generating a Latex summary table of the variables in my dataset using the `stargazer` package. I don't want percentile statistics (25th and 75th) in my table, but disabling the option via `iqr = FALSE` does not work.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thank you already for your help!

Here is an example:

```
library(stargazer)

d.x <- data.frame(rnorm(1000))

stargazer(d.x, iqr = FALSE)
```

The output is:

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Wed, Nov 07, 2018 - 10:15:23
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(25)} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(75)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        rnorm.1000. & 1,000 & 0.065 & 0.989 & $-$3.314 & $-$0.620 & 0.732 & 4.255 \\ 
        \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
        \end{tabular} 
        \end{table}
```

As you see the Latex output still includes the percentile statistics:

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(25)} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pctl(75)}
```

Answer (score 7):

Ah, I solved it myself: Instead of using the `iqr = FALSE` option, I can ommit the percintiles by adding `omit.summary.stat = c("p25", "p75")` to the function call to `stargazer`.

The full code is:

```
library(stargazer)
d.x <- data.frame(rnorm(1000))
stargazer(d.x, omit.summary.stat = c("p25", "p75"))
```

This gives the correct Latex-output without the percentiles:

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Wed, Nov 07, 2018 - 10:28:54
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
rnorm.1000. & 1,000 & 0.065 & 0.989 & $-$3.314 & 4.255 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: It is confusing that `?stargazer` mentions the `iqr` flag but it does not do anything.

Comment: Has anyone figured out why this is happening?